# SimpleMatrix difference matrix.mult(b) and matrix.elementMult(b)

Tags: java, linear-algebra, matrix-multiplication

I was looking through some code and came through this:

```
import org.ejml.simple.SimpleMatrix;

//this
simpleMatrix.mult(otherMatrix);
//and this
simpleMatrix.elementMult(otherMatrix);
```

What is the difference? Btw: I am really new to matrixes

Comment: Read the docs, first is matrix multiplication and the second is element by element multiplication. Docs:  [mult](http://ejml.org/javadoc/org/ejml/simple/SimpleBase.html#mult-T-) and [elementMult](http://ejml.org/javadoc/org/ejml/simple/SimpleBase.html#elementMult-T-). Wiki for more infos : [Matrix_multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication) and [Hadamard_product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices))

Answer (score 1):

Ah, found actual source code in another library.

**Element multiplication**

```
a, b, c;
d, e, f;

* (element multiplication)

g, h, i;
j, k, l;
```

results in a new matrix:

```
a*g, b*h, c*i;
d*j, e*k, f*l;
```

**Normal matrix multiplication:**
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2spTnAiQg4M